# How to manage single thread execution properly?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, single-threaded

I have a process that I want to be triggered by different sources.

Let's say we have one case where we habe some other process (let's call it "manualStarter") under certain conditions wants to trigger this main process. The main process takes a while to complete, let's say 10 seconds to 10 minutes. In case the process is already in progress while the manualStarter is trying to start it, it should not be queued more than once. The second process to trigger the start of the main process could be a "timedStarter" which would trigger the process once in a while, but only if the process is not running, else it would not queue the process to be triggered, instead would try it again some time later.

Now I've tried implementing this kind of process manager by using the isAlive() and join(), but it seems isAlive() is not reliable at all, until it changes its state to alive, 100 threads of this thread might get started (and do sometimes). So seems I couldn't rely on that.

Then I tried using the SingleThreadExecutor service which is closer to what I'm looking for, it's not blocking anything and it only allows a single thread to execute the process, so that's good, however I still don't know how to check the status/lock it properly, or how else I can ensure that the queue for starting the thread doesn't become larger than 1. I read a bit that semaphores are often used for similar kinds of tasks, but I am not sure how I could use them in this scenario.

So how could I achieve what I want? Do I need to implement my own ThreadPoolExecutor? How can I do it? Is there any better way?

Comment: You can use synchronization using locks and some flag to achieve your desired property for the threads.

Comment: @WasiAhmad yeah, I belive that's what I'm having problems to understand - where and how to use them?

Comment: Just wondering: wouldn't it be easier to not trigger a thread, but maybe add some command object into some **queue**? In other words: just have your outer sources emit commands into the same queue; and than a component regularly scans the content of that queue and calls that thread (if required). Just push new commands, and the queue does the job of "ah, we are currently running, so that one can be discarded"?!

Comment: @GhostCat how can that be achieved effectively? So that it is started as soon as it would be triggered, and we wouldn't have 2 processes at the same time and it wouldn't queue it up more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a shared flag so the manual starter knows if the thread is running. For example:

```
// Schedule this to run periodically via ScheduledExecutorService
class ManualStarter {
    private final AtomicBoolen isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

    public void run() {
        if (!isRunning.getAndSet(true)) {
            // It wasn't running so this will start it
            exec.submit(new MainProcess(isRunning));
        }
    }
}


class MainProcess extends Runnable {
   private final AtomicBoolean isRunning;

   MainProcess(AtomicBoolean isRunning) { this.isRunning = isRunning; }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       // do whatever it does
       isRunning.set(false);
   }
}
```

Then somewhere you schedule the main thing to run periodically doing something like:

```
ScheduledExectorService sched = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ManualStarter starter = new ManualStarter();
// Every 10 seconds will check if MainProcess is running and will start
// it if it's not
sched..scheduleAtFixedRate(starter, 0, 10, SECONDS);
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks quite realistic, at least from the first look, I'm trying to understand it better, but it might be how I had imagined it but didn't know how to achieve, hmm.

Comment: Good use of Atomic types. This was glossed over in the other answers.

Comment: @ArturasM it's just one way to do it. note that I didn't actually try this so I wouldn't be surprised if there's bugs or compile errors, but hopefully it's enough to give you a rough idea.

Comment: This is how it should be done. This ommits the need to use additional synchronization.

Comment: Hmm, just a couple of more questions to this, if I do submit for the executor  service, how do I know how many times the submit has been made and how can I ensure that it has not been done more than once? I find it useful to create another AtomicBoolean flag scheduledNextRun and I can then set it as true as soon as I do submit for the second time because I would already know that the process is running already, the problem here is where do I change the scheduledNextRun flag back to false after the second execution completed?

Comment: `isRunning.getAndSet(true)` does two things: (1) it returns the value that was present for `isRunning` and (2) it ensures the current value is `true`. So, if the process was already running `getAndSet` will return true and the submit won't happen (we only hit the submit line if `getAndSet` returned false). Conversely, if `getAndSet` returns false we've now ensured that any future calls to `getAndSet` will return true and we call `submit` on the executor. `getAndSet` will continue to return true until `MainProcess.run` reaches it's end and sets it back to false.

Comment: That's correct, but in my case, I also need to schedule 1 (but just 1 and not more) run right after the process completes, for that I added another flag scheduledNextRun which I set on true after I submit another task to SingleThreadExecutor, seems I need to also pass the scheduledNextRun into the mainProcess and that works fine. Now the problem is with the timedStarter which - should start the process if the process is not running, BUT if the process is running, it has to wait until the process completes and then wait defined amount of time and the try to start the process (or wait again...)

Comment: And currently it works up to that point, but I can't make the timedStarter to work as described, I can just schedule it to start once in a while and to trigger the process normally, but the problem is, the time interval between the runs triggered by the timedStarter is too small, since if the process itself takes a long time and timedStarter may start it too soon, so there might barely be a pause between the runs. But so far your examples were working guys, thanks for that, but it's just this one part that I'm still struggling with...

Comment: Hmm, I figured the only way I can get the "timedStarter effect" is if I create an object of timedStarter when finished processing in the mainProcess, then it keeps the required minimum time interval, as well as the manualStarter can still trigger the process whenever it needs to, the only drawbacks in this case are that it doesn't feel clean and is also very prone to any unexpected crashes within the main process, hmm.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for that. There is couple of implementations available (including [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that allows you to schedule deffered and/or repeating tasks - check [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)). Just pick one that fits your needst the best.

As for conditional execution the task is simple. Define some sort of accessible flag that holds the current "state" of given task. If it is running - do nothing, if it is not running - schedule execution.

Simple example:

```
//our flag 
private volatile AtomicBoolean isRunning=new AtomicBoolean(false);

public void scheduleTask(){
    if(isRunning.get()){
        return; // do nothing
}else{
    synchronized(isRunning){
     if(isRunning.get()){
      return;
}else{
     isRunning.set(true)
    scheduleNewTask();
}
}
}
}
```

For any how-tos check the [official Oracle's documentaion about Executors.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)
I have use AtomicBoolean in this example to mock "mutable" boolean. This can be done with `boolean` as well but synchronization needs to be done on different object (eg. dedicated `private Object lock=new Object();`)

Comment: This is not free from the race condition described

Comment: The SingleThreadExecutor is an ExecutorService. The accessible flag is exactly what I'm currently struggling, I need to set it effectively so that is it set to locked as soon as the process trigger is requested and unlocked as soon as the process execution is finished.

Comment: @Ivan it is - simple synchronization in scheduling method and we are thread safe.

Comment: @ArturasM just synchronize access to that flag. You will be most probably using something that is called double-check-locking. To all voices saying that it is broken - no it is not broken and works fine with `volatile` variables.